# Liquigraph schema files missing?

Tags: neo4j, xsd, liquigraph

We have a service in our site that uses neo4j for the database. Today when I tried to load up the service for development the project bombs out. I'm getting errors like this:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquigraph' defined in class path resource [org/liquigraph/spring/starter/LiquigraphAutoConfiguration$LiquigraphConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'changelog'.
```

and this:

```
2021-08-02 14:43:41.516  WARN 9650 --- [  restartedMain] o.l.core.io.xml.ChangelogParser          : XSD validation warning : schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.liquigraph.org/schema/1.0/liquigraph.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

in my terminal.

I went to the [site listed in the error](http://www.liquigraph.org/schema/1.0/liquigraph.xsd) and it doesn't work. There is also [this one](https://liquigraph.github.io/schema/1.0/liquigraph.xsd) which is pretty similar but gives a 404.

our pom.xml file lists this for liquigraph:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.liquigraph/liquigraph-spring-boot-starter -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquigraph</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquigraph-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

In researching the project I saw something about running it "offline" or something. How can I get the project to load with the XSD files missing?

Comment: My bad, I messed something up when working the deployment of the new website, will fix it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed now.
I just deployed a new version of the website and misconfigured a couple of things (wrong `CNAME` file location, wrong schema files location).

https://www.liquigraph.org/schema/1.0/liquigraph.xsd and http://www.liquigraph.org/schema/1.0/liquigraph.xsd should work fine now.

More recent releases of Liquigraph also support schema location redirects such as the latest 3.x and 4.x. Make sure to upgrade!

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you. I'm getting a new error now about "The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>".." There haven't been any code changes in our site since the last time it worked so I'm wondering if this is some issue related to the XSD files maybe?

Comment: Oh reading up in the errors I found this which probably explains it: 2021-08-03 08:02:05.631 ERROR 16101 --- [  restartedMain] o.l.core.io.xml.ChangelogParser          : XSD validation error : s4s-elt-character: Non-whitespace characters are not allowed in schema elements other than 'xs:appinfo' and 'xs:documentation'. Saw '301 Moved Permanently'.

Comment: What version of Liquigraph are you using? We have had redirect-aware XML schema resolvers for a while now.
To permanently avoid the problem anyway, it's better to use the https:// URL instead of http://. But recent enough versions of Liquigraph should support the redirect.

Comment: Looking at the maven config I posted above I should be using 3.0.3 right? I didn't set up the project initially so maybe I'm not clued in to some config that I need to update.

Comment: Updating from 3.0.3 to 3.1.2 fixed the problem. Thank you!